# Why does extending a typescript class cause a react factory method to fail on compilation when it works on the base class?

Tags: inheritance, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on code that is many hundreds of lines long, but have boiled my issue down to the following example.  My question is why the Typescript compiler fails on one case, but succeeds when the underlying class is used.

The following code compiles just fine:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface ComponentProps {
}

class Component<P extends ComponentProps> extends React.Component<P, any> {
}

interface RootComponentProps extends ComponentProps {
    viewManager?: ViewManager;
}

class RootComponent<P extends RootComponentProps> extends Component<P> {

    static childContextTypes = {
        viewManager: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    private _viewManager: ViewManager;

    getChildContext(): RootComponentProps {
        return { viewManager: this._viewManager }
    };
}

class ViewManager {
    constructor(managedElement: HTMLElement, rootComponent: typeof Component) {
        const rootFactory = React.createFactory(rootComponent);
    }
}
```

If I make one change, however, altering "typeof Component" to "typeof RootComponent" in the constructor of ViewManager, the compiler (and VS2015 Intellisense) complains:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface ComponentProps {
}

class Component<P extends ComponentProps> extends React.Component<P, any> {
}

interface RootComponentProps extends ComponentProps {
    viewManager?: ViewManager;
}

class RootComponent<P extends RootComponentProps> extends Component<P> {

    static childContextTypes = {
        viewManager: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    private _viewManager: ViewManager;

    getChildContext(): RootComponentProps {
        return { viewManager: this._viewManager }
    };
}

class ViewManager {
    constructor(managedElement: HTMLElement, rootComponent: typeof RootComponent) {
        const rootFactory = React.createFactory(rootComponent);
    }
}
```

The error is in the argument to the React.createFactory method, and says:

> error TS2345: Build:Argument of type 'typeof RootComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.

VS 2015 Intellisense gives a bit more information when hovering over the argument to React.createFactory, namely:

> Type 'typeof RootComponent'provides no match for the signature '(props?:any, context?:any):ReactElement<any>'

Another odd quirk on all this.... if I remove or comment out the static "childContextTypes" in the RootComponent, then it all compiles fine, but when I run it in my working much longer application, I get runtime complaints about lack of childContextTypes.

I know this isn't really magic, but it seems like black magic to me at the moment and any clarifying insight would be most appreciated.

Comment: After experimenting a bit I'm pretty sure this is a bug. I would submit an issue on the TS repo.

Comment: I'm not getting the error you seem to get, are you sure that this code is causing problems for you?

Comment: Very sure I'm getting this.  But perhaps your experience points to a typings file issue.  My react typings file is from DefinitelyTyped on Github, but admittedly very out of date compared with React itself.  My goodness, the typing file claims to be for React v0.14.  Perhaps your typings files is more up to date.  Can you share where you got it from?

Comment: I'm using the same version of the definition file, there's nothing newer that I'm aware of (try installing it with @types and you'll get the same). Are you sure that the code you posted is enough to reproduce the error? Maybe there's something else in your code that isn't posted in your question that results in this error? (also, be sure to tag me when you reply so i'll be notified)

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer - I have found a workaround it seems.  While you were looking, I looked at the readme file with known issues on Github, and it provided an insight (see the answer I am about to write to this issue) that helps me get around the problem.  It still doesn't answer why I am seeing this issue and you are not, about which I remain curious, but at least I have a way to move forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing comments to question, I began to be suspicious of typings.  And I found the following [helpful gotcha](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react#reactcomponentp-s-subclass-members-arent-contextually-typed).

The key point is to add an explicit type annotation to my childContextTypes as follows:

```
static childContextTypes: React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    viewManager: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

This solves the rather obtuse compilation error.  I haven't yet worked and tested through whether all the code works, but this is certainly a workable workaround for this situation, and according to the link this should be fixed in Typescript 2.0.